# how to compare single value with multiple value in a row

Tags: r

> Hi I have a df as below

**name    | min_date     | max_date      | act_val    | A     | B    | C     | D
 sam    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    30724     38115  635   2541    26
fred    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    29270     38115  635   2541    26
hays    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    29270      38115  635   2541   26
prem    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    700       38115  635   2541    26
cains   2016-06-01   2016-06-27    24        38115  635   2541    26
alan    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    28        38115  635   2541    26
vincy   2016-06-01   2016-06-27    3000      38115  635   2541    26

> i want compare "act_val" with all other columns in order to get nearest >variable name i.e in row 1 , 30724 is near to value in A (30724 ~= 38115)

| name     | min_date    | max_date    |  act_val    | A     | B    | C    |  D  | near_column
 sam    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    30724     38115  635   2541    26   A
fred    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    29270     38115  635   2541    26   A
hays    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    29270      38115  635   2541   26   A
prem    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    700       38115  635   2541    26   B
cains   2016-06-01   2016-06-27    24        38115  635   2541    26   D
alan    2016-06-01   2016-06-27    28        38115  635   2541    26   D
vincy   2016-06-01   2016-06-27    3000      38115  635   2541    26   C

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please format your example

Comment: I guess if your numeric clumns starts from 5th position, then `names(df1)[5:ncol(df1)][max.col(-abs(df1[5:ncol(df1)]  - df1$act_val))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
df1$near_column <- names(df1)[-1][ max.col(-abs(df1[-1]- df1[,1]))]
df1$near_column
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "D" "D" "C"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, i have 2 more columns extra in my df  and i am trying to apply the above code :  Error in Ops.data.frame(df[-1], df[, 1]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: i have added the 3 more columns in my df